# RESTful APIs (Create, Read) with flask-restful

Tags: python, api, rest, mongodb, flask

I wrote this simple API to be able to send logs from the client to MongoDB. Even though this works and fits my need, I would like to point out some concerns that I have regarding the following:

1. Is it efficient to be calling the instance of MongoClient for every request?
2. Do I need to close the instance of MongoClient after the request is successful?
3. A more Pythonic way to return responses?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


USER = "user"
PASS = "pw"
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://%s:%s@test.mlab.com/test' % (USER, PASS)
PORT = 19788


def db_conn():
    client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI, PORT)
    return client

def insert_record(args):
    client = db_conn()
    replycode = 0
    try:
        db = client['test']
        posts = db.users
        posts.insert(args)
    except:
        replycode = 1

    return replycode

def select_record(args={}):

    client = db_conn()
    db = client['test']
    result = db.users.find(args)
    return result

class CreatUser(Resource):

    def post(self):
        try:
            content = request.get_json()
            if "Vehicle" not in content:
                return jsonify({"Result": "Vehicle number not in passed arguments"}), 400

            else:
                vehicle = content['Vehicle']

            reply = insert_record(content)
            if reply == 0:
                return jsonify({"Result" : "Successfully inserted user: " + vehicle}), 201
            else:
                return jsonify({"Result" : "Failed to insert data. Check logs for more details"}), 400

        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'Error' : str(e)}), 500

class ViewUser(Resource):
    def get(self):
        from bson import json_util

        results = select_record()
        final = []
        for result in results:
            result.pop("_id")
            final.append(result)

        return jsonify(results=final), 200

api.add_resource(CreatUser, "/api/create")
api.add_resource(ViewUser, "/api/view")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad. 1 & 2:

There is no need to open fresh connection for, and close it after request.
`MongoClient` has connection-pooling built in, so only thing you need to do is to create instance of `MongoClient` with connection parameters and optional pool size.
It will open connection on first usage and in case it gets closed or times out - reopen them when needed.

A good way to do, would be to build a plugin wrapping `MongoClient` like they did with SQLite in [this example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/#the-extension-code).
Such plugin can be used afterwards as *persistent* connection - all logic regarding connecting/keeping/reconnecting will happen inside, thus simplifying resource methods.
But it is not necessary, instance of `MongoClient` can be created in global scope and imported into functions in same way like you did with `db_conn()`.

Ad. 3:

IMHO there is nothing wrong with `jsonify` since Flask-RESTful recognises Flasks response objects.
But, as they show in [here](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) you don't need to do it and you can return dicts directly:

```
class Todo3(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # Set the response code to 201 and return custom headers
        return {'task': 'Hello world'}, 201, {'Etag': 'some-opaque-string'}
```

I would also recommend putting `USER`, `PASS`, `MONGO_URI`, `PORT` into [configuration file](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/), so they can be easily overridden by environment variables on production.

Also [Artyom24](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/152705/128228) pointed out nice improvements regarding API RESTfulness

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but is it really necessary to wrap the `MongoClient`? Or it just depends on how complicated the project gets?

Comment: no, it is not mandatory, you can create `MongoClient` instance in global scope and then use it in functions.

Updated my answer to include this for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

The `MongoClient` was designed to be instantiated once per app life cycle, so this is redundant. You should try to reuse `MongoClient` instances as much as possible. Basically the only reason to create a new instance is if you want to configure it in a different way.

Also you've mentioned your `API` is supposed to be `RESTful`, so a few notes here:

1) To deal with user resource you should include it in the uri in pluralize form and distinguish actions you are performing by standard http codes, like the following:

`/api/users POST` - to create a new user

`/api/users/{userId} GET` - to fetch an existing one by `userId`

2) when you a new user is created it is a good practise to return `201 (Created)` http code together with the full url to fetch the user which has been just created, like: `http://yourdomain.com/api/users/{userId}`

3) "Failed to insert data. Check logs for more details" - it doesn't look like a `400 Bad Request`, as the user didn't make any mistake with input params. I suppose it must be either `500` (if the issue is related to something like a database error for example) or `403` `Forbidden` if any of implicit domain rules has been violated

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, i will try to apply your notes on my next iteration! :)